# LESS: How to specify current tag with nesting?

Tags: css, less

I have next CSS:

```
.button {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
}

a.button {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

I want to remake it with LESS, something like:

```
.button {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;

    a& {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }
}
```

But it generates next (wrong) CSS:

```
.button {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
}

/* unexpected space */
a .button {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

How can I do it right?

Comment: It seems like a LESS compiler mistake. I hope it will be solved in future

Comment: looks like a bug to me. for now I'd recommend just writing the two styles separately even though it's a bit more verbose.

Comment: Which version of LESS are you compiling with? `a&` works after version 1.3.0.

Comment: lessc 1.3.0 (package node-less from Ubuntu 12.10 repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally a version issue. As @freejosh commented, it is resolved in latest releases of LESS. If you take your code above to http://less2css.org/ then it works fine (which is running LESS 1.3.3, though you can change the version to 1.3.0 and see that it no longer functions as you expect and puts the space in).

Since you state you are running lessc 1.3.0, you need to upgrade your LESS version.

Answer (score 1):

These elements are not necessarily nested, and therefore LESS nesting doesn't apply.

Comment: Well, I have simplified my example. Further I use this .button as a mixin for other buttons. In this case I will have to copy-paste the same piece of code for each of them

Comment: Why not use a proper mixin, like .button-black?

Comment: That wouldn't solve the problem - I will still need to copy-paste a.mixin-name over and over again

Answer (score 0):

It isn't beautiful, but it works! :)

```
.button {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
}

a,b,other{
    &.button{
        .button;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this should work for `.button` 
But what if I want then to use .button as a mixin? E.g.:

        .red-button {
            .button;
            background-color: red;
        }

I think that I will have to copy-paste second part of the code :(